# Angularjs typescript compiler error due to lack of interface definition

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular so please bear with me.

I get the following compile error "
    error TS2339: Property 'Results' does not exist on type 'Object'.

The line that fails to compile is below (Results is an array).

```
req = http.post(url, [{...}])
  .subscribe(
    res => {
    console.log(res);
    var resp = res.Results[0].results.map(x => {
    return {id: x.ID, severity: x.CVSS, cve_link: x.link };
    } );
```

From what I read, I need to declare and interface definition for Results but I'm not sure how to declare that. Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: post the `res` object

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the shape of your expected response with an interface, something like:

```
interface MyResponse {
  Results: {
    results: {
      ID: string,
      CVSS: string,
      link: string,
    }[]
  }[]
}
```

And then you can tell the compiler that's what you expect from `.post` with syntax like:

```
req = http.post<MyResponse>(url, [{...}])
  .subscribe(
    res => {
    console.log(res);
    var resp = res.Results[0].results.map(x => {
    return {id: x.ID, severity: x.CVSS, cve_link: x.link };
    } );
```

There is a bit on this in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response).